# Filter SQLAlchemy one-to-many with "does not contain"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to query and filter on a one-to-many relationship and cannot seem to figure out how to do this.

Here are my mappings (trimmed for brevity):

```
class Bug(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bug'
    id = Column('bug_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = relationship('Tag', backref='bug')

class Tag(Base):
    id = Column('tag_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('tag_name', String)
    bug_id = Column('bug_id', ForeignKey('bug.bug_id'))
```

I want to be able to find all bugs that do not have tag with name "foo".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what the `Tag` table is supposed to represent for you, but it is odd that your schema associates each `Tag` with exactly one `Bug`. If you want to tag multiple `Bug`s with a tag of the same name, you will be creating multiple rows in the `Tag` class with the same `name`. This would seem to violate the [3rd normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form).

The standard way to describe a tag cloud in a database would be to use a many-to-many relationship with a secondary "association" table that associates (bug,tag) pairs. The SQLAlchemy docs have a [very nice tutorial on this pattern](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-many-to-many-relationship).

**If** you stick with your schema as-is, there are several ways to do it.

## Client-side filtering

This is obviously inefficient but it is easy to understand. You go through the bugs one by one, go through their tags one by one, and eliminate the bugs where `tag.name=="foo"`:

```
non_foo_bugs = [ bug for bug in session.query(Bug)
                 if not any(tag.name=="foo" for tag in bug.tag) ]
```

## Two queries

Find all distinct bugs that **are** tagged "foo", and then find the complement of that set.

This version uses exactly two queries of the database:

```
foo_bugs = [t.bug_id for t in session.query(Tag).filter_by(name="foo").distinct()]
session.query(Bug).filter(~Bug.id.in_(foo_bugs))
```

## One query with a subquery

Same as the above, but make `foo_bugs` a subquery, since there's no reason to fetch its contents on the client side:

```
foo_bugs = session.query(Tag.bug_id).filter_by(name="foo").distinct().subquery()
session.query(Bug).filter(~Bug.id.in_(foo_bugs))
```

This would be an uncorrelated subquery, so from the server point of view it should be optimized just about the same as two separate queries.

Comment: Your assessment of how the data is mapped being "wrong" is correct. I'm actually mapping an existing database structure that I have read-only access to so I'm making do with what I have. Thank you for the complete answer and multiple options!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `any()` operator on the relationship.

```
bugs_without_foo = session.query(Bug).filter(
    db.not_(Bug.tags.any(Tag.name == 'foo'))
).all()
```

It's nicer to look at, but it [could be less efficient over very large data sets](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any) than the subquery from Dan Lenski's answer.